# mostrar resultados de múltiples filas en una sola fila mysql

Tags: mysql

cordial saludo,
estoy realizando una consulta para mostrar los logros perdidos de un estudiante, y que los resultados se me muestren en la misma fila segun el logro perdido.
por ejemplo andrea perdio L2 y L3 como se ven en la imagen, andres perdio L1, L2,L3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado de la consulta me regresa los valores correctamente pero en diferente columna
es resultado que espero sería:

```
matematica  andrea  L2 3.100  L3 2.800
matematica  andres  L1 3.200  L2 2.2000 L3 3.200
```

```
SELECT
a.ID,
a.asigna,
a.ESTUDIANTE,
( CASE WHEN a.IDLOGRO = '1' THEN a.nota ELSE '' END ) AS L1,
( CASE WHEN a.IDLOGRO = '2' THEN a.nota ELSE '' END ) AS L2,
( CASE WHEN a.IDLOGRO = '3' THEN a.nota ELSE '' END ) AS L3
FROM
    nivela AS a
WHERE
a.estado = 'REPITE' 

GROUP BY
    a.idlogro,
    a.ESTUDIANTE,
    a.asigna
ORDER BY
    a.asigna, a.ESTUDIANTE ASC
```

de antemano agradezco la guia que me brinden para resolver es caso

estructura de tabla

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for nivela
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nivela`;
CREATE TABLE `nivela`  (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IDLOGRO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASIGNA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTUDIANTE` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTA` float(11, 4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTADO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 7 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of nivela
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (1, '1', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 3.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (2, '2', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 2.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (3, '3', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 3.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (4, '1', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 3.5000, 'APRUEBA');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (5, '2', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 3.1000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (6, '3', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 2.8000, 'REPITE');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: ¿Es esta pregunta útil? [¿Puedo concatenar varias filas de MySQL en un campo?](/questions/527057/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente cambia los `CASE ... WHEN` por una combinación de `GROUP_CONCAT()` y `CONCAT()`.

He aquí la descripción de estas dos funciones:

##### [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> Esta función devuelve un resultado de cadena con los valores no `NULL`
> concatenados de un grupo. Devuelve `NULL` si no hay valores que no
> sean `NULL`.
>
> En MySQL, puede obtener los valores concatenados de combinaciones de
> expresiones. Para eliminar valores duplicados, utilice la cláusula
> `DISTINCT`. Para ordenar valores en el resultado, use la cláusula
> `ORDER BY`. Para ordenar en orden inverso, agregue la palabra clave
> `DESC` (descendente) al nombre de la columna por la que está ordenando
> en la cláusula `ORDER BY`. El valor predeterminado es el orden
> ascendente; esto se puede especificar explícitamente usando la palabra
> clave `ASC`. El separador predeterminado entre los valores de un grupo
> es la coma (`,`). Para especificar un separador de forma explícita,
> use `SEPARATOR` seguido del valor literal de la cadena que debe
> insertarse entre los valores del grupo. Para eliminar el separador por
> completo, especifique `SEPARATOR ''`.
>
> El resultado se trunca a la longitud máxima proporcionada por la
> variable de sistema `group_concat_max_len`, que tiene un valor
> predeterminado de `1024`. El valor se puede establecer más alto,
> aunque la longitud máxima efectiva del valor devuelto está restringida
> por el valor de `max_allowed_packet`. La sintaxis para cambiar el
> valor de `group_concat_max_len` en tiempo de ejecución es la
> siguiente, donde val es un entero sin signo:
>
> ```
> SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
> ```
>
> El valor de retorno es una cadena binaria o no binaria, según si los
> argumentos son cadenas binarias o no binarias. El tipo de resultado es
> `TEXT` o `BLOB` a menos que `group_concat_max_len` sea menor o igual a
> `512`, en cuyo caso el tipo de resultado es `VARCHAR` o `VARBINARY`.
>
> Si se invoca `GROUP_CONCAT()` desde el cliente [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), los
> resultados de la cadena binaria se muestran usando notación
> hexadecimal, según el valor de `--binary-as-hex`. Para obtener más
> información acerca de esa opción, consulte la [Sección 4.5.1, “mysql:
> el cliente de línea de comandos de MySQL”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

##### [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

> Devuelve la cadena que resulta de concatenar los argumentos. Puede
> tener uno o más argumentos. Si todos los argumentos son cadenas no
> binarias, el resultado es una cadena no binaria. Si los argumentos
> incluyen cadenas binarias, el resultado es una cadena binaria. Un
> argumento numérico se convierte a su forma de cadena no binaria
> equivalente.
>
> `CONCAT()` devuelve `NULL` si algún argumento es `NULL`.

Por lo dicho en la definición de `GROUP_CONCAT()`, sacamos a `a.idlogro` del `GROUP BY`, porque el valor se agrupará dentro de `GROUP_CONCAT()`, permitiendo que haya una sola fila por cada grupo, que es lo que quieres.

He puesto además `MAX(a.ID) AS ID,` porque sin eso tu consulta no pasa la restricción *`only full group by`*. Las versiones antiguas de MySQL son demasiado permisivas con eso, produciendo código no válido en SQL estricto. Eso cambió desde MySQL 8 y conviene que actives siempre *`only full group by`*.

Aquí tienes todo en un fiddle:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for nivela
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nivela`;
CREATE TABLE `nivela`  (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IDLOGRO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASIGNA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTUDIANTE` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTA` float(11, 4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTADO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 7 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Records of nivela
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (1, '1', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 3.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (2, '2', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 2.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (3, '3', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDRES', 3.2000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (4, '1', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 3.5000, 'APRUEBA');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (5, '2', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 3.1000, 'REPITE');
INSERT INTO `nivela` VALUES (6, '3', 'MATEMATICA', 'ANDREA', 2.8000, 'REPITE');
```

```
SELECT
    MAX(a.ID) AS ID,
    a.asigna,
    a.ESTUDIANTE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT('L',a.IDLOGRO,' ',a.nota) 
        ORDER BY a.idlogro 
        SEPARATOR ' '
    ) AS g 
FROM
    nivela AS a
WHERE
a.estado = 'REPITE' 
GROUP BY
    a.ESTUDIANTE,
    a.asigna
 ORDER BY
  a.asigna, a.ESTUDIANTE ASC;
```

| ID | asigna | ESTUDIANTE | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | MATEMATICA | ANDREA | L2 3.1000 L3 2.8000 |
| 3 | MATEMATICA | ANDRES | L1 3.2000 L2 2.2000 L3 3.2000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JfVGriOF)

Comment: muchas gracias. me funciono perfectamente